# Modulo in If statement being treated as statement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a javascript program that will count to 100, however, for every number divisible by 3, it will instead say 'divisible by 3' instead of displaying number

I'm using modulo to find out which numbers are divisible by 3 but my if statement is being treated as a statement rather then a conditional.

https://jsfiddle.net/gyoyfv7L/

My Code

```
    var i = 1;
while (i < 101){

    if(i % 3 = 0){
        $("#main").append("divisible by 3");
    }
    else{
         $("#main").append(i + '<br />');
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: change i % 3 = 0 with i % 3 == 0

Comment: Why this question gaining up votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is for assignment. You want `==` or `===` for equality checking.

```
if(i % 3 == 0){
// ------^^
```

or

```
if(i % 3 === 0){
// ------^^^
```

`==` is "loose" in that it does type coercion using JavaScript's (sometimes surprising) rules. `===` is "strict" in that it will always be false when comparing values of different types.

---

Side note: When you have a loop consisting of an initialization of a control variable, a test of that variable, and an unconditional update of that variable at the end, it's better to use the idiomatic loop construct for that (`for`) rather than `while`:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    if(i % 3 == 0){
        $("#main").append("divisible by 3");
    }
    else{
         $("#main").append(i + '<br />');
    }
}
```